# cohomology class of subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^n$ in $H^p(\mathbb{P}^n, \Omega^p)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is the exercise III 7.4 of Hartshorne.
If you don't have this text in your hand, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794757/cohomology-class-of-a-subvariety).

I'm trying (b): If $X = \mathbb{P}^n$, identifying $H^p(X, \Omega^p)$ with $H^0(X, \Omega^0) = k$, show that $\eta(Y) = \deg Y$, the degree of the subvariety $Y$.

I have shown this in the case that $Y$ is a point (this is exactly (a), I think.) and the case that $Y$ is the intersection of $n-p$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n$.
($p$ is the codimension of $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$.)
And I have shown that by Bertini and Bezout there exists $n-p$ hyperplanes $H_1, \cdots, H_{n-p}$ such that the number of points of $Y \cap H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_{n-p}$ is the degree of $Y$.
I think these results are sufficient to show this exercise, but I can't show.

The hint says that cut with a hyperplane, and reduce to the case that $Y$ is a set of finite points.

Thank you very much!